# Python - iteration in <type:'list'> how do you iterate list into table or tabular

Tags: python, csv

```
list1 = ['1213.3213.23', 'first', 'hary: 7', 'Class :First1'
         '23324.3434.3434', 'sec', 'amer: 7', 'Class :Second2']
```

How do I convert this above list into table form like below :

```
1213.3213.23     first  hary:7  Class :First1 
23324.3434.3434  sec    amer:7  Class :Second2
```

I am trying to convert them and then write them into csv file or text file
I am facing difficulty at

1. converting the lines into table form
2. write the result into csv file or text file

Comment: Is that really what `list1` looks like? Are you sure it's not a list of lists?

Comment: yes, this what it looks like and its in a list form. your post has solved it. tqvm

Comment: See the `grouper` recipe in the documentation for the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = ['1213.3213.23', 'first', 'hary: 7', 'Class :First1'
         '23324.3434.3434', 'sec', 'amer: 7', 'Class :Second2']

with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in (L[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(L), 4)):
        outfile.write('\t'.join(row))
```

Or for a csv file:

```
import csv
with open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.Writer(fout)
    outfile.writerows((L[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(L), 4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['1213.3213.23', 'first', 'hary: 7', 'Class :First1'
         '23324.3434.3434', 'sec', 'amer: 7', 'Class :Second2']
```

Assuming this is just a list that you want to write into a 4 column CSV, your first step would be to split your list into a list of lists.

```
list_of_lists = [list1[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(list1),4)]
```

Then you use Python CSV module to write to CSV.

```
import csv

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(list_of_lists)
```